# How to replace the deprecated "observers" on a Subject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I use the following code:

```
  @Output() click: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hasHandler = this.click.observers?.length > 0;
  }
```

`observers` is [noted as deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) but I can't find the replacement; do you have any ideas on how I can replace/refactor it?

Comment: Why do you care whether or not the event is observed? The whole point of the pattern is that your component emits events without having to check whether 0, 1 or many observers receive them (which may also change over time...). But note there _is_ an undeprecated [`observed` property](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/72bc92191ab959e27a969dc4476e14d95416573f/src/internal/Subject.ts#L106-L108).

Comment: Legacy code that check if a div have observers to apply specific type on it : 

```ts
[ngClass]="{'heroInputContainer__content--clickable' : hasHandler}"
```

Comment: But that's only checked in `ngOnInit`; what happens if ever that changes?

Comment: Thanks for the observed property it does the exact same code that I used to do :) 

For your other question, It won't change after the onInit we set this style only once. But we use this code on other components where the are no observers so different style will be set

Answer (score 1):

Although `observers` is indeed marked as deprecated:

> Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made internal in v8.

there's still `observed`, whose implementation is almost identical to your current code:

```js
  get observed() {
    return this.observers?.length > 0;
  }
```

Comment: But is there another (new) way to get the exact number of observers?

Comment: @Konrad as mentioned above the subject shouldn't care how many observers it has, the point of the pattern is decoupling.

Comment: _(I'd guess "are there any?" is supported because you might be able to avoid some work if the answer is "no", but "how many?" isn't a sensible question to ask.)_